# What is fileAPI ? How do I use it with angular?

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, fileapi

I'm creating a function so that I can upload files to my server through the use of AngularJS. While browsing I saw this amazing piece of work on github by daniel farid ( *link - https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload* )
But the problem is its too much for me to understand. I'm starting out with more of basic stuff. 
I'd be delighted to hear back from you. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a concrete question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this directive in the controller.

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Html

```
 <input type="file" name="file" class="file-input-wrapper btn btn-default btn-primary" file-model="uploadFile" id="control" />
```

while going back to your controller:
the uploaded file will be available within the `$scope.uploadFile`